# Pause video with jquery

Tags: javascript

I've got probably very simple question but I cannot figure it out myself:

`var video = $("myVideo"); video.pause();`

I am trying to prevent the video from playing on page load (so I can later play it on mouse enter).
It says it's not a function.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`video.pause()` is not a jQuery function, you need to get the DOM object, easy way to do that is `video[0]`, so try `video[0].pause()`.